# Security implication of prefixing type name with parent namespace name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ndepend

NDepend, automatically suggests 
**avoid** prefixing type name with parent namespace name

Is this due to security/threats possible?

Answer (score 2):

This rule has nothing to do with security. It is just about unecessary redundancy. From the rule description:

> This rule warns about situations where the parent namespace name is
>   used as the prefix of a contained type.
>
> For example a type named "RuntimeEnvironment" declared in a namespace
>   named "Foo.Runtime" should be named "Environment".
>
> **Such situation creates naming redundancy with no readability gain.**